# Cart conditions won't save to table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have products with and without conditions in my cart, when I add my cart data to `orders` table all my cart data will save except my products conditions.

dd of `my cart` data:

```
CartCollection {#699 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    2 => ItemCollection {#670 ▼
      #config: array:6 [▶]
      #items: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "product two"
        "price" => 50000.0
        "quantity" => 2
        "attributes" => ItemAttributeCollection {#671 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            "attr" => array:2 [▼
              "name" => "weight"
              "value" => "2"
            ]
          ]
        }
        "conditions" => array:1 [▼
          0 => CartCondition {#672 ▼
            -args: array:4 [▼
              "name" => "12 inch"
              "value" => "25000"
              "type" => "additional"
              "target" => "item"
            ]
            -parsedRawValue: 25000.0
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

dd of `same cart` when I try to save in `orders` table:

```
Order {#680 ▼
  #fillable: array:16 [▶]
  #events: array:1 [▶]
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #attributes: array:15 [▶]
  #original: array:15 [▼
    "product_data" => "{"2":{"id":2,"name":"product two","price":50000,"quantity":2,"attributes":{"attr":{"name":"weight","value":"2"}},"conditions":[{}]}}"
    "user_id" => 1
    "ordernu" => 9358964473
    "address_id" => "1"
    "orderstatus_id" => 1
    "quantity" => 2
    "payment_id" => null
    "buyer_name" => "John Doe"
    "note" => null
    "buyer_email" => "admin@admin.com"
    "phone" => "006281200000000"
    "price" => null
    "updated_at" => "2018-02-18 13:03:41"
    "created_at" => "2018-02-18 13:03:41"
    "id" => 10
  ]
```

As you see my conditions `"conditions":[{}]}` is empty.

Here is my save function:

```
 //save cart to orders table and remove items from it
    public function checkout(Request $request)
    {
      $cartItems = Cart::getContent();

      try {
        $order = new Order();
        $status  = Orderstatus::where('title', 'Witing Payment')->value('id');
        $qty = Cart::getTotalQuantity();
        $order->product_data = $cartItems; //save cart data as json
        $order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $order->ordernu = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
        $order->address_id = $request->input('address_id');
        $order->orderstatus_id = $status;
        $order->quantity = $qty;
        $order->payment_id = $request->input('payment_id');
        $order->buyer_name = $request->input('buyer_name');
        $order->note = $request->input('note');
        $order->buyer_email = $request->input('buyer_email');
        $order->phone = $request->input('phone');
        $order->price = $request->input('totalPriceInTotal');
        dd(Auth::user()->orders()->save($order)); // dd results
        Auth::user()->orders()->save($order);

        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
            $product = Product::find($item->id);
            $product->decrement('stock', $item->quantity);
        }

      $user = $order->buyer_email;
      event(new UserOrdered($order));

      //Cart::clear(); //clear cart info
      Session::flash('success', 'Thank you. Your order has been received.');
      return redirect()->route('ordersindex');
      }catch (Exception $e) {
         return response($e->getMessage(), 400);
      }
    }
```

any idea?

## UPDATE

this is how i add products in my cart session:

```
public function addingItem(Request $request, $id)
    {
      //finding product
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
      //get product weight
      $weight = $product->weight;
      //list of discounts
      $discounts = Discount::all();
      //get current time
      $mytime = Carbon::now();

      // get product weight in cart
      $weightArray = [
        'attr' => [
              'name' => 'weight',
              'value' => $weight,
        ]
      ];

      // add product conditions to cart
      $customAttributes = [];
      if(!empty($request->attr)){
          foreach($request->attr as $sub) {
          // find the suboption
              $sub = Suboption::find($sub);
              if (!empty($sub->id)) {
                  $itemCondition1 = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(
                    [
                      'name' => $sub->title,
                      'value' => $sub->price,
                      'type' => 'additional',
                      'target' => 'item',
                    ]
                  );
                  array_push($customAttributes, $itemCondition1);
              }
          }
      }

      //adding product and options to cart
      Cart::add(array(
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->title,
        'price' => $request->input('harga'),
        'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
        'attributes' => $weightArray,
        'conditions' => $customAttributes,
      ));
      //success message in return
      Session::flash('success', 'This product added to your cart successfully.');
      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

## UPDATE 2

Well I've been playing with codes and I came to this code:

```
public function checkout(Request $request)
    {
      $cartItems = Cart::getContent();
      foreach($cartItems as $item){
          if (is_array($item['conditions'])) {
            foreach($item['conditions'] as $condition){
              $arsd = [
                'name' => $condition->getName(),
                'value' => $condition->getValue(),
              ];
             return $arsd;
            }
        }
      }
```

which is returning this: (what i need)

[image: screen2]

```
    "product_data" => "{

"16":{"id":16,"name":"new product","price":100000,"quantity":"1","attributes":{"attr":{"name":"weight","value":"56"}},"conditions":[{"args":null},{"args":null}]},

"4":{"id":4,"name":"product four","price":1500000,"quantity":"1","attributes":{"attr":{"name":"weight","value":"45"}},"conditions":[{"args":null}]},

"1":{"id":1,"name":"product one","price":10000000,"quantity":"1","attributes":{"attr":{"name":"weight","value":"1"}},"conditions":[]}
} ◀"
```

now the issue is how to apply this in my `conditions` part of my code? when I dd my cart while saving to database (`orders` table) this is what I get:

[image: screen3]

> Note: products with id 16 & 4 supposed to have conditions and id 1
>   doesn't have any condition.

Now, anyone there can help with that?

## UPDATE 3

Well again I played more with codes and now I have conditions in my orders table (with 1 issue)

```
foreach($cartItems as $item)
      {
          $item->id; // the Id of the item
          $item->name; // the name
          if(is_array($item['conditions']) && !empty($item['conditions'])) {
            foreach($item['conditions'] as $key => $value)
            {
              $item['conditions'] = [
                    'name' => $value->getName(),
                    'value' => $value->getValue(),
                ];
            }
          }
          $item->price;
          $item->quantity; // the quantity
          $item->attributes; // the attributes
      }
```

Result:

```
"product_data" => "{"4":{"id":4,"name":"product four","price":1500000,"quantity":"1","attributes":{"attr":{"name":"weight","value":"45"}},"conditions":{"name":"12 inch","value":"25000"}}} ◀"
```

> The issue is I only get 1 condition in my table while my item has 2
>   conditions.

any idea on that?

Comment: can you show how `$cartItems` is set?

Comment: @Webinion set in where?

Comment: I mean, can you show DB query or Eloquent code which is assigned to `$cartItems` collection,

Comment: there is no database or eloquent for cart, it uses session, after I saving my cart session to `orders` table just then I have database data.

Comment: ohh, a collection will have from `attributes` only, you need to move your conditions inside, `attributes`, it would be better if you show your session code for adding items.

Comment: @Webinion updated my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165464/discussion-between-webinion-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this on your checkout function.

```
public function checkout(Request $request)
{
    $cartItems = Cart::getContent();
    foreach($cartItems as $item){
        if (is_array($item['conditions']) && !empty($item['conditions']) {
            foreach($item['conditions'] as $condition){
                $arsd = [
                    'name' => $condition->getName(),
                    'value' => $condition->getValue(),
                ];
                array_push($item['conditions']['args'], $arsd);
            }
        }
    }
    return $cartItems;
}
```

UPDATE:

> The issue is I only get 1 condition in my table while my item has 2 conditions.

*You only get 1 `condition` while your item originally has 2 `conditions` because it's previous value is just being overridden by the other `condition` instead of adding it to a stack during the loop. Saving the conditions on a `$temp` variable when iterating on the `item conditions` might fix that. See updated code below:*

```
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    $item->id; // the Id of the item
    $item->name; // the name
    if (is_array($item['conditions']) && !empty($item['conditions'])) {
        $temp = [];
        // get the subtotal with conditions applied
        $item['price_sum'] = $item->getPriceSumWithConditions();

        foreach ($item['conditions'] as $key => $value) {
            $temp[] = [
                'name' => $value->getName(),
                'value' => $value->getValue(),
            ];
        }

        $item['_conditions'] = $temp;
    }
    $item->price;
    $item->quantity; // the quantity
    $item->attributes; // the attributes
}
```

Comment: `Indirect modification of overloaded element of Darryldecode\Cart\ItemCollection has no effect`  on `array_push($item['conditions']['args'], $arsd);`

Comment: I updated my answer based on your `UPDATE 3`, you can check it out if it's working on your end or not

Comment: thank you is exactly like what Yunus answered me and I'm sure will work, my issue continued with this comment on Yunus answer please read the following comments after that you might have solution for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848996/cart-conditions-wont-save-to-table-in-laravel/48920365#comment84847221_48920365

Comment: Can you try saving the `priceSumWithConditions` on other variable and see if it works? `$item['price_with_conditions'] = $item->getPriceSumWithConditions();`

Comment: I tried dd it i got ` if( $condition->getTarget() === 'item' )` it's killing me, each time has error i have to flush sessions and add products to cart again!

Comment: it seems you put that after you set the `$item['conditions'] = $temp`. I updated my code above, can you try it?

Answer (score 1):

may be you can try the following

```
foreach($cartItems as $item)
      {
          $item->id; // the Id of the item
          $item->name; // the name
          if(is_array($item['conditions']) && !empty($item['conditions'])) {
            $conditions=[];
            foreach($item['conditions'] as $key => $value)
            {
                $conditions[]=[
                    'name' => $value->getName(),
                    'value' => $value->getValue(),
                ];

            }
            if(count($conditions)){
                $item->price=$item->getPriceSumWithConditions();
            }
            $item['conditions'] = $conditions;
          }
          $item->price;
          $item->quantity; // the quantity
          $item->attributes; // the attributes
      }
```

Comment: seem to be working, however my product price will stay the same, which i need to be change to sum of product and conditions here i have a method for that matter `$item->getPriceSumWithConditions()` but i need to place it in that if you presented just now. and say if have condition use `$item->getPriceSumWithConditions()` as the price otherwise just `$item->price` any idea how to place it in your code?

Comment: have a look at the answer again. i updated my answer, now it should change the price if there is any conditions.

Comment: `Call to a member function getTarget() on array` on this line on my package codes `if( $condition->getTarget() === 'item' )`

Comment: another issue is when I refresh my page the error goes to conditions if! not sure why? `Call to a member function getName() on array` on `'name' => $value->getName(),` i'm not even able to back to my cart i must flush my session :|

Comment: i updated my answer again. make sure this block does not execute on page refresh it should only execute before placing your order. can you show the definition of `getPriceSumWithConditions` method?

Comment: this is it https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart/blob/master/src/Darryldecode/Cart/ItemCollection.php

Comment: yes it doesn't return error but not change price also